# WEBGL autocompletion in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, webgl

I have a school project and i need to use WEBGL. But its pretty difficult to write all the code without autocompletion. I didn't find proper extension. Do you have ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for visual studio code to give you auto completion it needs to know the types of variables.

So for example if you have this

```
const gl = init();
```

VSCode has no idea what type the variable `gl` is so it can't auto complete. But you can tell it the type by adding a JSDOC style comment above it like this

```
/** @type {WebGLRenderingContext} */
const gl = init();
```

Now it will auto complete

[image]

The same is true for HTML elements. If you do this

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas');
```

VSCode has no idea what type of element that is but you can tell it

```
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
const canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas');
```

Now it will know it's an `HTMLCanvasElement`

[image]

And, because it knows it's an `HTMLCanvasElement` it knows that `.getContext('webgl')` returns a `WebGLRenderingContext` so it will automatically offer auto completion for the context as well

[image]

Note that if you're pass the canvas into some function then again, VSCode has no idea what that function returns. In otherwords

```
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
const canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas');
const gl = someLibraryInitWebGL(canvas);
```

You won't get completion anymore since VSCode as no idea what `someLibraryInitWebGL` returns so follow the rule at the top and tell it.

```
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
const canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas');

/** @type {WebGLRenderingContext} */
const gl = someLibraryInitWebGL(canvas);
```

You can see other JSDOC annotations [here](https://jsdoc.app/) if you want to document your own functions, for example their argument and return types.